# Difference between Prolog Project and Prolog Reference Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, prolog

What is the difference between a Prolog Project and a Prolog Reference Project? Both are the two Prolog-based options when creating a project in Eclipse ( currently using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.0 and Spider IDE).

Comment: Do you have a specific Prolog plug-in for Eclipse?  The Amzi! Prolog plug-in shows up in the New Project tree menu as "Prolog -> Project". AFAIK it does not create a "Prolog Reference Project" entry.

Comment: There's also [PDT for Eclipse](http://roots.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/) which is a plugin that interfaces with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: I currently use SICStus Prolog IDE, if this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what is meant by "Prolog Reference Project".  There is [a SICStus Prolog IDE](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/site/index.html) based on Eclipse which is called SPIDER (currently labelled as a public beta, but "already useful").  The "Prolog Reference Project" is "a project that will refer to all the SICStus Prolog library files."  See [SPIDER Getting Started](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/site/prerequisites.html).  Creating the Reference Project is the second (and final) step of setting up SPIDER.  "Once the Reference Project is created the set-up and installation of SPIDER is complete."

The regular Prolog Project is what one uses to build any new/custom application in SICStus Prolog.  So you'd choose this option to create any new projects, whereas the Prolog Reference Project will not generally need to be recreated except when the backend version of SICStus is being upgraded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I came across the same explanation from Sicstus Prolog IDE web page: "The second step is to create a Reference Project, that is a project that will refer to all the SICStus Prolog library files". I definitively overlooked it when I was looking at the instructions for setting up SPIDER. Thanks indeed, I.